# How to check if the Spreadsheet is opened in a browser inside a trigger function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way of checking if the current Spreadsheet is open in a browser inside a trigger? I want a few triggers to only run if I have the Spreadsheet open in the browser. Otherwise, if it is closed, I want it to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation / Potential Solution:

You can't know if a spreadsheet is open at the time you execute a trigger.

But based on your description, you want some `code` to run when the spreadsheet is open.

I think you can very well use an [`onOpen` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene):

> The onOpen(e) trigger runs automatically when a user opens a
> spreadsheet that they have permission to edit.

Therefore you can include some code under this trigger function and it will be executed as soon as (and only) you open the spreadsheet file:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // this code will be executed only when you open the spreadsheet
}
```

**Please note:**

Again, this is a trigger function and you are not supposed to execute it manually. It will be executed itself at the time you open the spreadsheet file.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that wouldn't work since my trigger runs every 5 minutes.

Comment: There is no other solution. You can tweak the code to loop itself every 5 minutes (you can use `Utilities.sleep`. But the code has to be inside the `onOpen` function. @VitorDurante

Comment: Thank you! In that case, I will make a few attempts to at least predict if the user has the spreadsheet open.

Comment: In addition to Marios answer I'd like to say that at this time there is no onClose trigger which would make easier to achieve your goal. Consider opening a new feature request for this purpose or upvote the following opened request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757543 which might be similar to your workaround.